# Approximating a recursive equation that is circular but diminishing

Tags: approximation, recursive-algorithms

First time posting, so happy to hear feedback on how I can write a better question. My background in recursive equations is limited to solving linear recurring relations. I have a challenging problem that is quite different than that. Excuse my lack of familiarity with the lingo, I’ll try to best explain my issue in layman terms.

I’d appreciate any resources I could read up on to learn more about this kind of problem.

Suppose we have the following recursive equation:

$f(n) = \frac{37}{38}(1 + f(n-1)) + \frac{1}{38}(1 + f(n + 35)); f(0) = 0$

This seems to diminish asymptotically, but my knowledge is too limited to determine a solution for the asymptote or even to approximate the solution with code.

I began an attempt to approximate this with some code, but got stuck when I realized that this is circular. When $f(n+35)$ is being computed, it’ll eventually recursively reach my starting point and loop infinitely. For example, if I’m trying to approximate $f(2)$, it’ll call $f(37)$, then keep calling $f(36)$, $f(35)$, ...$f(2)$ and loop all over again.

I’d definitely appreciate any resources or suggestions for approximating this or even better, determining the asymptote for any value of $n$. If this is intractable, oh well, but I’d love to learn more about why.

Comment: This is a $36$th order linear recurrence.  You need $36$ initial conditions.  As for the problem you mention, just write $m=n+35$.  Then rearrange to express $f(m)$ in terms of $f(m-35)$ and $f(m-36)$.  There's no loop, but you need more initial data.   Having said that, I strongly doubt there's a nice formula in any event.  The general solution will involve the roots of a $36$th-degree polynomial.

Comment: @saulspatz Thanks, this makes a lot of sense. I'll need to figure out how to determine the other initial conditions.